# How to find all lines in code where inheritance take place?

Tags: c++

Is there any tool/static analysis tool/build in compiler or IDE tool that can find all lines of code where inheritance take place?

What I want to do is to find all inheritance cases and then check if base class have virtual destructor.

Comment: Questions asking to find a software _tool_ are off-topic...

Comment: Virtual destructors are only needed when the **design** calls for the ability to delete objects of derived types through pointers to the base type. No tool will tell you what the design requires. For example, the code that I'm currently working on has dozens of classes that derive from base classes and have virtual functions; the base classes have **no** virtual destructors.

Comment: @PeteBecker I want to find places of code where inheritance occur automatically and then check base classes by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A global textual search for ":" will find all derived class definitions, however it will also have many false positives

A regex search for "(class|struct)\s+\S+\s+:" will cut down on most of the false positives